# Is there any way to delete those space between the 2 column?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, bootstrap-5

Hope you're all well. While I'm sick with this coronavirus, I'm trying to improve my web skills.
I'm trying to make a 2 column table with only span/li/ul.

Here is my code :

```css
body {
   background-color: #FEFAF6;
   font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular';
   font-size: 14px;
}

div.tableau_infor {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.fa-star {
   color : #154360;
}

.all_star {
   margin-left: 30px;
}

li {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 365px;
}

li:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name ="author" content="Ismaël Zemmouj">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <title>mel</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">1bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">2bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">3Abcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfher</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">4Abcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfher</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">5Abcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfher</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>



        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">6bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see the space in the picture below. Plus, I don't know why there is a space before the 1st and 2nd element of the 2nd column...

[image]

I'm not using a table because It's more easy to use the ul/il for the responsive design, isn't it ?

Cordially,

Comment: With the help of a friend, we did resolve the problem. I just needed to add this to the `li` element : `d-flex justify-content-between`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the fixed width from `li` and use `white-space:nowrap` instead then add `text-md-end` to your first columns to avoid the gap

```css
body {
   background-color: #FEFAF6;
   font-family: 'Segoe UI Regular';
   font-size: 14px;
}

.fa-star {
   color : #154360;
}

.all_star {
   margin-left: 30px;
   white-space:nowrap;
}

li {
   list-style-type: none;
   display:inline-block;
}

li:hover {
   background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-md-end">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">1bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">2bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-md-end">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">3Abcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfher</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      

        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">4Abcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfher</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-md-end">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">5Abcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfher</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>



        <div class="col-md-6">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <span class="">6bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</span>
              <span class="all_star">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. A question, when we go hover the text, we can see the red line, is it possible for it to be shown only over the text + stars ?

Comment: Perfect, thanks ! It's not easy to make our first website, I still have a lot of problems but that's why I'm doing it, to train myself ! Have a good day sir

Comment: Its me again. Well, there is a problem. This solution is good for the same amount of letter, but check this out : https://imgur.com/c98p63U

Comment: @Balaure I don't see any *problem*, This is the logical result of such structure. How you want it to be?

Comment: The line need to have the same length and the star need to be starting at the same point (left and right). Just like this : https://imgur.com/zgBLxNi

Answer (score 0):

1. The weird indentation of last row occured because you forgot to close one `<div>` tag. Use HTML validators to find these kinds of errors: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input You can just copy-paste code and click "Check" button.
2. To have super responsive control over elements, I would apply nested Grid behavior. Here is an example of single row code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">1bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <span class="col-md-6">2bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</span>
            <span class="col-md-6">
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
                <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: example of three column solution:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">1bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="col-md-6">2bcdeqgsterudisoqpardbfhert</span>
      <span class="col-md-6">
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
        <span class="fas fa-star"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you anwser. It works perfectly. I'm going to ask something else, sorry. Is it possible to put less space between the first column of star and the second column of the text ? Or since its rows we can't remove it ?

Comment: Sure, for example, you can use instead of two filled `col-md-6` three `col-md-4`. First one with content, than one `col-md-4` empty, than `col-md-4` with content. Checkout EDIT of my answer.