# Is it possible to have an icon (fontawesome) as a button using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

Hope you're fine.
What I'm trying to do is using an icon with fontawesome, and be able to use it as a button. Here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-6 align-items-stretch">
                <i class=""></i>
                 <a href="https://github.com/IsmaElzem?tab=repositories" class="fas fa-at fa-3x mt-3"></a>
                <p class="h5">Mail</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 align-items-stretch">
                 <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/isma%C3%ABl-zemmouj-02b235128/" class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x mt-3"></a>
                <p class="h5">LinkedIn</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

But if you are looking at the result, the icon is now bleu and there is a line under it. Is it possible to not have this color and remove the line under the icon please ?

Cordially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add some extra CSS to do this. This can help

```
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <style>
  a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:orange;
  }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-6 align-items-stretch">
                <i class=""></i>
                 <a href="https://github.com/IsmaElzem?tab=repositories" class="fas fa-at fa-3x mt-3"></a>
                <p class="h5">Mail</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 align-items-stretch">
                 <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/isma%C3%ABl-zemmouj-02b235128/" class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x mt-3"></a>
                <p class="h5">LinkedIn</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do accept the answer if it has helped My friend and do also vote :)

Comment: Could you check my other post about the column please... I'm stuck... (my last comment on Temani Afif post...)

Comment: Why not. I would love to help my friend :) Could you share the link here. I would have a look at the code and try to solve that :)

Comment: Here is the link, if you have any other possibility to discuss, I'm open (discord...) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65465576/is-there-any-way-to-delete-those-space-between-the-2-column/65465638?noredirect=1#comment115742092_65465638

Comment: What are you confused about Dear Balaure. The spacing I guess... Let's have a discussion to clear your doubts :) Could you share the discord link

Comment: I tried to sign in the discord but I am unable to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226495/discussion-between-imran-rafiq-rather-and-balaure).

Answer (score 1):

How about this css code?

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: If you want to change css when hover, can add hover event.

Comment: Can you vote my answer, please? I think my code is similar to @Imran Rather's answer. Thank you.